# python script to recursively search FTP for specific filename and newer than 24 hours

Tags: python, recursion, ftp, ftputil

Our storage area ran into trouble with SMB connections and now we have been forced to use FTP to access files on a regular basis. So rather than using Bash, I am trying to use python but I am running into a few problems. The script needs to recursively search through the FTP directory and find all files "*1700_m30.mp4" newer than 24 hours. Then copy all these files locally.

this is what I got so far - but I can't seem to get the script to download the files or get the stats from the files that tell me whether they are newer than 24 hours.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import sys
import os
import ftplib
import ftputil
import fnmatch
import time

dir_dest = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST1/' # Directory where the files needs to be downloaded to
pattern = '*1700_m30.mp4' #filename pattern for what the script is looking for 
print 'Looking for this pattern :', pattern # print pattern


print "logging into GSP" # print 
host = ftputil.FTPHost('xxx.xxx','xxx','xxxxx') # ftp host info
recursive = host.walk("/GSPstor/xxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx",topdown=True,onerror=None) # recursive search 
for root,dirs,files in recursive:
    for name in files:
        print 'Files   :', files # print all files it finds
        video_list = fnmatch.filter(files, pattern)
        print 'Files to be moved :', video_list # print list of files to be moved 
        if host.path.isfile(video_list): # check whether the file is valid 
            host.download(video_list, video_list, 'b') # download file list 



host.close
```

Here is the modified script based on the excellent recommendations from ottomeister (thank you!!) - the last issue now is that it downloads but it keeps downloading the files and overwriting the existing files:

```
import sys
import os
import ftplib
import ftputil
import fnmatch
import time
from time import mktime
import datetime
import os.path, time 
from ftplib import FTP


dir_dest = '/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST1/' # Directory where the files needs to be downloaded to
pattern = '*1700_m30.mp4' #filename pattern for what the script is looking for 
print 'Looking for this pattern :', pattern # print pattern
utc_datetime_less24H = datetime.datetime.utcnow()-datetime.timedelta(seconds=86400) #UTC time minus 24 hours in seconds
print 'UTC time less than 24 Hours is: ', utc_datetime_less24H.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # print UTC time minus 24 hours in seconds
print "logging into GSP FTP" # print 


with ftputil.FTPHost('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxx','xxxxxx') as host: # ftp host info
    recursive = host.walk("/GSPstor/xxxx/com/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxx",topdown=True,onerror=None) # recursive search 
    for root,dirs,files in recursive:
        for name in files:
            print 'Files   :', files # print all files it finds
            video_list = fnmatch.filter(files, pattern) # collect all files that match pattern into variable:video_list
            statinfo = host.stat(root, video_list) # get the stats from files in variable:video_list
            file_mtime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(statinfo.st_mtime) 
            print 'Files with pattern: %s and epoch mtime is: %s ' % (video_list, statinfo.st_mtime)
            print 'Last Modified: %s' % datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(statinfo.st_mtime) 
            if file_mtime >= utc_datetime_less24H: 
                for fname in video_list:
                    fpath = host.path.join(root, fname)
                    if host.path.isfile(fpath):
                        host.download_if_newer(fpath, os.path.join(dir_dest, fname), 'b') 

host.close()
```

Comment: shouldn't host.close read host.close()

Comment: the ftp connection seems to close fine without () - but it also works with ()

Comment: @JRM: `host.close` without the `()` doesn't do anything, although the connection will probably be closed when your script exits.

Comment: I will change the script accordingly - thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
    video_list = fnmatch.filter(files, pattern)
```

gets you a list of filenames that match your glob pattern.  But this line:

```
    if host.path.isfile(video_list): # check whether the file is valid
```

is bogus, because `host.path.isfile()` does not want a list of filenames as its argument.  It wants a single pathname.  So you need to iterate over `video_list` constructing one pathname at a time, passing each of those pathnames to `host.path.isfile()`, and then possibly downloading that particular file.  Something like this:

```
    import os.path

    for fname in video_list:
        fpath = host.path.join(root, fname)
        if host.path.isfile(fpath):
            host.download(fpath, os.path.join(dir_dest, fname), 'b')
```

Note that I'm using `host.path.join()` to manage remote pathnames and `os.path.join()` to manage local pathnames.  Also note that this puts all of the downloaded files into a single directory.  If you want to put them into a directory hierarchy that mirrors the remote layout (you'll have to do something like that if the filenames in different remote directories can clash) then you'll need to construct a different destination path, and you'll probably have to create the local destination directory hierarchy too.

To get timestamp information use `host.lstat()` or `host.stat()` depending on how you want to handle symlinks.

And yes, that should be `host.close()`.  Without it the connection will be closed after the `host` variable goes out of scope and is garbage-collected, but it's better to close it explicitly.  Even better, use a `with` clause to ensure that the connection gets closed even if an exception causes this code to be abandoned before it reaches the `host.close()` call, like this:

```
    with ftputil.FTPHost('xxx.xxx','xxx','xxxxx') as host: # ftp host info
        recursive = host.walk(...)
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for all this -- let me try and put it into action. I am trying to download all files into a single directory.

Comment: Also no symlinks - just binaries

Comment: Just tried it this morning and it is working like a charm. Just need to put the newer than into action. Thank you for the help.